# Add a link in the label of a Joomla form element

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to add a link to a field in the joomla contact form. I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<field name="contact_terms"
        type="checkbox"
        id="contact-terms"
        description=""
        label="I agree to <a href='http://example.com/terms'>Terms and Conditions</a>"
        default="0"
        value="1"
        required="true"
    />
```

but it gives an error and I'm just very very new to joomla. How should it be done?

Comment: Well, which error it gives then?

Comment: I would suggest you use a language constant for this instead which will solve your problem.